# How to use flash player to encode and push a live stream to media server?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rtmp, wowza

I have a media server ([Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/)) that I am pushing a live RTMP stream to and playing it (in several protocols HLS/RTMP) back in the browser with [Flowplayer](https://flowplayer.com).

Currently I am encoding the stream with [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) but I would like to also give my users an option to encode from within the browser with Flash.

**Do I need to learn ActionScript and write my own SWF to access the camera/mic and push the stream?**

**Is there a commercial SWF file with parameters I can pass in (such as the RTMP stream URL etc)?**

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [flash](/questions/tagged/flash) to send Video from webcam to Wowza. Video will encoded by Flash
2. use [webrtc](/questions/tagged/webrtc) send video to Wowza. Video will encoded by Web Browser

I have used https://github.com/theintencity/flash-videoio. It not bad.
Please note - Latest browser not enable flash by default